# Apache2: Redirect from a custom link to a html file

Tags: redirect, apache2, virtualhost

That's quite a simple question, but I would like to create a redirection for my website using Apache2 and the virtual hosts.

I want it to happen when a user gets on this link : `https://somewebsite.com/test`
And this link should redirect to an html file in my website directory (for example `test.html`) with the link still on `https://somewebsite.com/test`

I think I should use mod_rewrite or the aliases but I don't know how to use them.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Please see here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)